# How to resize and rotate the image view by dragging it right corner of the image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation, image-resizing, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi I have a requirement where i need to resize and rotate the image view by dragging it right corner of the image view.

I could successfully resize the image view by dragging its corner, but failed when i am trying to implement the resize cum rotate feature for the image view with one-finger.

Can any one please guide me to achieve my requirement.

I have added the code below for resizing the image view from its corner edge.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
isResizingLR = (self.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && self.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingUL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingUR = (self.bounds.size.width-touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y<kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingLL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && self.bounds.size.height -touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
```

}

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGPoint previous=[[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:self];

float  deltaWidth = touchPoint.x-previous.x;
float  deltaHeight = touchPoint.y-previous.y;

if (isResizingLR) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y,touchPoint.x + deltaWidth, touchPoint.y + deltaWidth);
}  
if (isResizingUL) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth, self.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight, self.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, self.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);
} 
if (isResizingUR) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x ,self.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  self.frame.size.width + deltaWidth, self.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);      
} 
if (isResizingLL) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth ,self.frame.origin.y ,  self.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, self.frame.size.height + deltaHeight);   
}

if (!isResizingUL && !isResizingLR && !isResizingUR && !isResizingLL) {
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + touchPoint.x - touchStart.x,self.center.y + touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi resizing the `UIImageView` by this code sample [Here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/spuserresizableview)

try this ...

i hope it will help you...

try this for rotate...

```
self.imgViewForBend.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,1.0);
self.imgViewForBend.layer.position = CGPointMake(200,300.0);
CGAffineTransform cgaRotateHr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(3.141/4));
[self.imgViewForBend setTransform:cgaRotateHr];
```

Comment: Thanks Spynet, but this code helps me to resize rather i would need some samples to rotate the imageView the same way as resizing...

Comment: refer this http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2012/05/24/how-to-rotate-a-uiimageview-roulette-tutorial/

Comment: refer this too http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4181-rotating-an-uiimageview-around-an-arbitrary-point.html

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I would think of something like this...

When touch begins store the start point and also the center point of the image you are editing.  (All point relative to the superView of the image).

Then the scale is relative to the distance of the touch from the center point (use pythagorus).

Also, you will know the angle of the line from the center point to the original touch (use trigonometry).  You can change the angle of the image based on the difference between the start angle and the current angle.

I'd also take the logic out of the touches moved and touches began functions.  Make a calculateRotation function and a calculateScale function to help.

Can't code at the moment though.

Comment: Surely that is your part? :) You'll need a couple of variables, one to store the start distance between the initial touch and the center point. One to store the initial angle.  Then you'll need a function to calculate the angle and one to calculate the distance. Then based on how the angle and distance changes you can scale/rotate the image accordingly.